# gfortran complains about rank of element in structure constructor for allocatable component

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Consider the following code:

```
subroutine tao_show_this ()
implicit none

type b_struct   
integer, pointer :: good_user => null()
end type

type a_struct   
 type (b_struct), allocatable :: value_ptr(:)
end type

type (a_struct) a
a = a_struct()

end subroutine
```

Compiling with gfortran 5 or 7 gives:

```
gfortran -c test.f90
test.f90:4:13:

 type b_struct
             1
Error: The rank of the element in the structure constructor at (1) does not match that of the component (0/1)
```

This code compiles fine with ifort. Is this a gfortran bug or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Reported bug to gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87568 . Marked "Confirmed from 4.8 up to trunk (9.0)."

Answer (score 1):

For a default structure constructor, being able to omit the value for an allocatable component is a feature introduced in Fortran 2008.

gfortran does [not currently support this feature](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status) ("Unimplemented features").

To leave the component not allocated while still giving a value to the constructor one references `null`:

```
a = a_struct(NULL())
```

As DavidS comments, this exists as [a reported bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87568).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the full answer since the error message is about a rank mismatch as opposed to a problem with an uninitialized variable. In fact, if "value_ptr(:)" is replace by "value_ptr" in the above example the code compiles without problem. Also if the integer pointer component in b_struct is replaced by a simple integer there is no problem with compiling.

Comment: Does it work as you expect using `null`?  The error message is indeed confusing (talking about having a scalar value when there is no value given at all) but this could simply be a lack of correct diagnostic as well as a lack of support.

Comment: Yes it does work with null. But the fact that the code compiles fine without using null if the b_struct is modified coupled with the incorrect error message indicates to me that in actuality gfortran is meant to support default structure constructors for allocatable components and that this is a "bug". In any case, I will report this to the gcc folks to see what they say.

Comment: Talking to gcc people a sound idea, and unfortunately I currently can't test some ideas about why some things may appear to work.  However, guessing I'd day that with allocatable scalar being a F2003 addition rather than F2008, tests and such may just not be quite compatible yet.